# Examples of induction on the sum of numerator and denominator

Tags: induction, rational-numbers

I am currently teaching induction and one of my students ask if we can use induction over rational numbers, i.e. to prove a statement $P(q)$ is true for all $q\in\mathbb Q$.

I remembered reading examples that induct over $m+n$, where we write $q=\frac mn$. I forgot where I read it though. Can anyone come up with some simple examples?

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to reduce this to induction over integers by indexing the rationals with integers as is usually done, in order of m+n, i.e. 1/1, 1/2, 2/1, 1/3, 2/2, 3/1, etc...?

Comment: Good luck finding a propositoin about rationals that that allows you to conclude its truth for a numerator-denominator sum from the truth for smaller sums

Comment: @LiliFN Yes. And I want to find an example on that.